# Selenium IDE - Wait for pop up right place

Tags: ajax, popup, selenium-ide

I run a Selenium IDE test on a website where lots of pop-up appear to explain the website. The process is

- Popup (with same id) appears with specific text
- Pop up move to the right place to explain an icon or another part of the website

Problem is that the "move to the right place" takes time. So my selenium IDE test continues without waiting. Then pop up conflicts appears and my test failed.

I can force it to "Pause" but this is not a clean solution. Does Selenium IDE have something like "WaitNoAjaxActionOnThePage"

I try "WaitForElementPresent" or "WaitSpecificText" but it does not resolve the problem with the previous logic.

Well I hope its clear,

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is not enough powerfull to deal with ajax ou CK editor. So I move to Selenium driver. There are more possibilities.
http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/